# Mac mini temperature issue

Tags: mac, mac-mini, temperature

I have old mac mini upgraded from 1,1 to 2,1 and CPU from T2300 to t7200. Now I have some troubles with my smcFanControl. It show than my temperature is 73-80 celsium when cpu is loaded.
Is it ok temp for this apparat???

Maybe i need install old macOSx? Now i have installed MacOSX Lion 10.7.5 ?

Comment: if look in this table http://www.intelmactemp.com/profile/638 looks it's a normal temperature. This thing make me think that i can't trust apple if they shows small Computer and it's hot like keatle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is better to look at the CPU load, that will result in heating up.

Intel designs microprocessors to operate up to 110 Celsius, before the build in thermal switch kicks in to prevent self destruction.

70 Celsius is almost the standby temperature (room + CPU)

Intel has made a easy to use [app to check your CPU health](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20). See if it works on your model.

Comment: i found that with snow leo mac working much better and loading it like it's doing lion.